# Merging Columns from the Same File in Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
Name2 381 3923 1000
Name2 321 323  9000
Name2 121 212  1000
Name3 321 644  4444
Name3 111 342  4234
Name3 342 323  3232
```

I want to merge the first three columns only into something like this:

```
Name2:381:3923 1000
Name2:321:323  9000
Name2:121:212  1000
Name3:321:644  4444
Name3:111:342  4234
Name3:342:323  3232
```

However, I want to preserve any other column present in the file.  I tried with sed and regex, but the problem I have is that I need to preserve other columns, and simply substituting out spaces for colons messes that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{sub(/ /,":");sub(/ /,":")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** `sed` solution.

```
sed 's/ /:/1;s/ /:/1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  I think because my file is tab-delmited.  So should I change s/ / to s/\t/?

Comment: Or use `/[[:blank:]]+/` to match a sequence of (horizontal) whitespace